# Download files (game mods) from a website

Tags: linux, debian, wget

**My goal:**
To run a script or command every day in order to get the newest mods which were released in the Transport Fever 2 mod section.
https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/

This is an example of a mod, where the file you can download is th the bottom.
https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?entry/5107-%C3%B6bb-%C3%A4ra-valousek-%C3%B6bb-1012-%C3%B6bb-1014-%C3%B6bb-1163/

I played around with wget already but I was only able to download the index.php files (I am a Beginner in Linux).

I think the problem is, that they host the files on a third party hoster.

Does anyone has an idea how I can achieve my goal? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sketchy website requires login before I can view it.

Comment: @jesse_b no you should be able to access it without logging in

Comment: You need to accept the Teams of Service first in order to have access to the Forum

Comment: `curl -OJ 'https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?entry-download/5107-%C3%B6bb-%C3%A4ra-valousek-%C3%B6bb-1012-%C3%B6bb-1014-%C3%B6bb-1163/&fileID=7290'` downloads `markus1014_oebb_valousek_1.zip` for me

Comment: This works too: `curl -OJ $(curl -fs 'https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/' | grep -om1 '[^"]*entry-download[^"]*')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/ provides a link to the newest file. It's possible to download the html document of the site with `curl`, pipe the output to extract the download link (done in a flimsy way below with `grep`) and using command substitution, pass this link to a second `curl` command.

```bsh
curl -OJ \
    $(curl -fs \
    'https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/' | \
    grep -om1 '[^"]*entry-download/[^"]*')
```

Hopefully that gives you something to build on.

---

`grep` options used:

- `-o` / `--only-matching` to output only the matching pattern, instead of the entire line which contains the pattern
- `-m 1` / `--max-count=1` stops searching the input after the first line containing a match
- The pattern to match: `[^"]*entry-download/[^"]*`: the download links all seem to be given with `href="https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?entry-download/<number><...>"` – so the above pattern matching seems sufficient: zero or more of any character other than double quotes `"`, followed by `entry-download/`, followed again by zero or more of anything other than `"`

`curl` options used (first pass – inside the substitution):

- `-f` / `--fail` don't output anything if we recieve a [`4/5xx` http reply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) – the request failed, we don't want to grep an html document which tells us that it failed
- `-s` / `--silent` this is the first pass, we don't want to see a progress bar or anything

second pass `curl` options – these download links use a `content-disposition` header to tell us the filename, so:

- `-O` / `--remote-name` save the file using the same name as the remote file
- `-J` / `--remote-header-name` allows the `-O` option to use the server-specified Content-Disposition filename instead of extracting a filename from the URL

---

There is actually more than one `entry-download/` link – to download all the links, we can remove `-m1` from `grep` & adjust the second `curl` options to use `--remote-name-all`, like this:

```bsh
curl --remote-name-all -J \
    $(curl -fs \
    'https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/' | \
    grep -o '[^"]*entry-download/[^"]*')
```

---

### File conflict checking:

If we want to know the filename described by the `content-disposition` header in advance, an extra step will be required. We can use curl to send a `head` request:

```bsh
# get first url from the page, storing it to
# the parameter 'url' so we can use it again later
url=$(curl -fs \
    'https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/' | \
    grep -om1 '[^" ]*entry-download/[^" ]*')

# head request to determine filename
filename=$(curl -Is "$url" | grep -iom1 '^content-disposition:.*filename="[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$')

# 'if' statement using the 'test' / '[' command as the condition
if test -e "$filename"; then
    echo "$filename exists!"
else
    # a file named $filename doesn't exit,
    # so we'll download it
    curl -o "$filename" "$url"
fi
```

- this is a simple exmaple which checks for a conflicting file, before attempting to download
- isn't really necessary as `curl -J` won't overwrite existing files, but I suspect you want to check for presence of `"$filename"` – maybe without the `.zip`: `"${filename%.zip}"` – in some other directory, or maybe in some text file

Building on the above, if you wanted to do this for all extracted `entry-download/` urls:

```bsh
# extract all urls, placing them in an array parameter 'urls'
urls=( $(curl -fs \
    'https://www.transportfever.net/filebase/index.php?filebase/80-transport-fever-2/' | \
    grep -o '[^" ]*entry-download/[^" ]*') )

# loop over extracted urls
for i in "${urls[@]}"; do
    # do filename extraction for "$i"
    # use filename to determine if you want to download "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very great explanation and it also works great! Now I am putting that into a script. Just need to search how I can say the script something like "If this mod is already in this Folder then ignore it"

Comment: @Ch0p I'm glad this helped. As the filename-from-header complicates things somewhat, I updated the post with some notes about it.